# Stack Overflow question and answer RSS feeds should have titles so users can promote their usage using http://ifttt.com RSS feed tasks

Tags: support, feed

Stack Overflow question and answer RSS feeds should have titles, so users can promote their usage using http://ifttt.com RSS feed tasks.

The URL I am trying to use for questions: https://stackoverflow.com/users/72057/foreachdev?tab=questions.

The URL I am trying to use for answers https://stackoverflow.com/users/72057/foreachdev?tab=answers.

The validation error `ifttt.com` returns is the following one.

[image: Screenshot]

Ghost of Billy: There has to be a better way!

Comment: What is "Ghost of Billy"?

Answer (score 8):

The URLs you give aren't RSS feeds at all, they are normal page links to your user profile.

The RSS feeds I know do have a title (e.g. [the RSS feed for this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/123487) has one).

You should consider using your user feed ([your feed on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/72057)) - it is linked on the bottom of your profile page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" ...>
    <title type="text">User foreachdev - Stack Overflow</title>
```